# iOS 6 addAnnotation EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but okay on iOS 7

Tags: ios, mkmapview, exc-bad-access

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this strange crash on iOS 6.

I'm building an app for iOS 6 - iOS 7 and I am using a `MKMapView` with a single `MKPointAnnotation` added to it.  I am also using a custom `MKAnnotationView` to display my pin and callout. On iOS 7 everything works beautifully.  However, iOS 6 I'm getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on `MKMapView:addAnnotation`.  Everything is done on `viewDidLoad`.

I've tested 2 scenarios as well.

1. If I set the `MKMapView` delegate before I add the annotation it crashes on iOS 6.
2. If I set the `MKMapView` delegate after I add the annotation it does not crash on iOS 6, but `viewForAnnotation` is not called and I end up with the default pin and not my custom pin and callout.

Code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set delegate
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    //lat, long
    CGFloat latitude = 40.689249f;
    CGFloat longitude = -74.0445f;

    //coord, span, region
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05f, 0.05f);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coord, span);

    //annotation
    MKPointAnnotation annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [annotation setTitle:@"title here"];
    [annotation setCoordinate:coord];

    [self.mapView setRegion:region];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];//EXC_BAD_ACCESS here (iOS 7 no crash)
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    CAnnotationView *annotationView = (CAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:MKAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier];

    if (!annotationView)
        annotationView = [[CAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:MKAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier];

    return annotationView;
}
```

Ok well I found out that loading a custom nib for my CAnnotationView in iOS 6 is causing a crash. If I comment out loading the bundle then no more crash.

So are nibs not supported when subclassing MKAnnotationView in iOS 6?

```
-(id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self){
      NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CAnnotationView" owner:self options:nil];
      self = [bundle firstObject];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Here is a small test I created that replicates the crash. Run on iOS 6 you will get crash, iOS 7 you should see the custom annotation placed on the MKMapView. http://www.levieggert.com/MKMapView/MKMapViewCrashTest.zip

Comment: Show the code where you allocate the annotation. Also, show your code for viewForAnnotation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed by changing File Owner's Class to CAnnotationView and then making the top level view in the nib an outlet which I added as a subview.

```
-(id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self){
      [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CAnnotationView" owner:self options:nil]; 
      [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any other way around this?